# slapd version not upgraded

Tags: ldap, slapd

I have just upgraded my openldap to 2.4.59.

But when I execute `slapd -V`, it still shows my previous version : 2.4.44?

```
root@VLDAP ~]# ldapsearch -V
ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch 2.4.59 (Mar 13 2024 01:11:59) $
    root@VLDAP.MIGKVDC:/root/openldap-2.4.59/clients/tools
    (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20459)


root@VLDAP ~]# slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (Aug  4 2017 14:23:27) $
    mockbuild@c1bm.rdu2.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd
```

Comment: How did you install it? Did you build it yourself? Are you picking up the binary in sbin first before local sbin? What does `which ldapsearch` & `which slapd` give you?